# HTTP 403 Forbidden url error when access to docker container IIS setting server

Tags: asp.net, .net, docker, iis, window

[Image of success call the swagger inside of the docker container](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qwq33.png)

I success to start the Server in the docker container.

With the simple image of the Docker file, I install the dotnet sdk and hosting bundle, and set the IIS with command line.

I success to start the API Server with IIS and check with using curl inside of the docker container.

(Image is attached)

But, when I tried to call the outside from docker container, for example in my laptop, the only response is 403 Fordden url comes out.

[HTTP 403 forbidden url error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lxq3D.png)

I tried to compare with my local IIS setting, but every setting is exactly same.

No Managed code, and the Advance setting is same.

What's the problem?

This is the docker file I use.

```
# escape=`
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:ltsc2019

SHELL ["powershell", "-Command"]
RUN Install-WindowsFeature Web-ASP


ADD https://download.microsoft.com/download/1/2/8/128E2E22-C1B9-44A4-BE2A-5859ED1D4592/rewrite_amd64_en-US.msi rewrite_amd64_en-US.msi
RUN Write-Host 'Installing URL Rewrite' ; Start-Process msiexec.exe -ArgumentList '/i', 'rewrite_amd64_en-US.msi', '/quiet', '/norestart' -NoNewWindow -Wait;
WORKDIR /app
COPY ./ /app


RUN mkdir C:/inetpub/wwwroot/api
COPY ./api C:/inetpub/wwwroot/api

EXPOSE 8080
```

and I install the dotnet-sdk3.1, dotnet-hosting-6.0.4

Please give me some advice.

Thanks in advance

I'm trying to containerize my server made with window and dotnet 3.1
But I got problem while I tried to access to exposed port.

Comment: What command did you use to launch the container? If you didn't map the ports correctly, HTTP requests on `localhost:8080` can be dispatched to another place, and 403 is not surprising.

Comment: docker run -it --name my_api -p 8080:8080 -v myfolder:dockerfolder my_image

Comment: I create iis setting with the port binding to 8080
appcmd add site /name:api /bindings:"http://localhost:8080" /physicalPath:"C:\app\api"

Comment: I checked, if inside of the container, with curl command, the API is running well.
But I cannot access from outside of the container

Comment: You will have to use a site binding that allows external traffic to enter the container. A localhost binding only accepts traffic from within the container like you observed.

Answer (score 0):

> By default, when you create or run a container using docker create or
> docker run, it does not publish any of its ports to the outside world.
> To make a port available to services outside of Docker, or to Docker
> containers which are not connected to the container’s network, use the
> --publish or -p flag. This creates a firewall rule which maps a container port to a port on the Docker host to the outside world.

For more information about container networking, please refer to this manual: https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/container-networking/